# Splunk Dedup by _time and Combine Values for One Field Into One Event

Tags: duplicates, splunk, splunk-query, splunk-calculation

I am working with Exchange 2010 data. I have the MessageID, Sender, Recipients, and _time. Depending on the event type, recipients can be split (i.e. all recipients for a given message are not included in the event, but are split across multiple events). Here is an example of the data:

```
_time    MessageID    Sender    Recipients
4:25      <12345>     Sender1   Recipient1
4:50      <12345>     Sender1   Recipient2
```

I use this query to combine multiple Recipients values into one event, by MessageID and Sender:

```
index=ExchangeIndex sourcetype=MSExchange:2010:Message tracking
| stats values(Recipients) as recip by MessageID, Sender
| table _time, MessageID, Sender, recip
```

This results in:

```
_time     MessageID   Sender    recip
          <12345>     Sender1   Recipient1; Recipient2
```

_time is not populated, because `values` wouldn't work if _time was included in the `by` statement since each event for a particular MessageID happens at a different time. Therefore, I need to somehow `dedup` MessageID (to get the latest _time) and stuff Recipients values simultaneously.

I attempted this:

```
| stats max(_time) as datetime by MessageID, Sender
| stats values(Recipients) as recip by datetime, MessageID, Sender
| table datetime, MessageID, Sender, recip
```

But this doesn't work either, and it results in recip not being populated:

```
_time    MessageID    Sender    recip
4:50     <12345>      Sender1
```

My desired output looks like this:

```
_time     MessageID   Sender    recip
4:50      <12345>     Sender1   Recipient1; Recipient2
```

How should I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

I think I see what your saying.. The receipt and sender do not have the same timestamp so they can never be in the same row?

If so then try this below.. This assumes the receipt and sender are within 10 minutes of each other

```
index=ExchangeIndex sourcetype=MSExchange:2010:Message tracking
| bin _time span=10m
| stats values(Recipients) as recp values(MessageID) AS MessageID 
  values(Sender) AS Sender by _time
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
index=ExchangeIndex sourcetype=MSExchange:2010:Message tracking
stats latest(_time) as latestTime, values(Recipients) as recip by MessageID, Sender
table latestTime, MessageID, Sender, recip
convert ctime(latestTime)
```